# Install r-cran-rgdal on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, rgdal

When I try to install `r-cran-rgdal` I get an error message saying that `r-cran-rgdal` depends on `r-api-3.5` and `r-cran-sp`, that I hold broken packages. Then when I try to install `r-api-3.5`. It does not work either. How can I solve this problem?

Here is the message show in portuguese

```
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:  
r-cran-rgdal : Depende: r-api-3.5
               Depende: r-cran-sp (>= 1.1-0) mas não será instalado 
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is:  What R version are you running, and where did you get it from?  Many of us, myself included, run the binaries built at the Launchpad PPA managed by Michael and [mirrored at CRAN in the bin/linux/ubuntu directory](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html).

The second question builds on this. If you do (and this really is recommended) then you can take advantage of the 'cran2deb4ubuntu' PPA also maintained by Michael. It is (briefly) described [in the same README.html](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html).  If you set that then

```
sudo apt install r-cran-rgdal
```

will do the right thing. I just verified it again. Running `apt-cache policy r-cran-rgdal` then shows you both: the older binary *from the Ubuntu distro* and, more importanly, *the newer one from the PPA*:

```
$ apt-cache show r-cran-rgdal
Package: r-cran-rgdal
Source: rgdal
Priority: optional
Section: gnu-r
Installed-Size: 7463
Maintainer: cran2deb4ubuntu <cran2deb4ubuntu@gmail.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.5-18-1cran1.2004.0
Depends: r-cran-rcpparmadillo, libproj-dev, r-base-core, r-cran-sp, libc6 (>= 2.4), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libgdal26 (>= 3.0.1), libproj15 (>= 6.3.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.9)
Filename: pool/main/r/rgdal/r-cran-rgdal_1.5-18-1cran1.2004.0_amd64.deb
Size: 4314904
MD5sum: 39eeb74508acf7b1688001d8afe737e1
SHA1: ff5827e4785027e47184ea4c554695a365216f8e
SHA256: 8a7996db246a5d628ca110535253d9df8ec2ccad91c8d37c22de262fbe2d2d21
Description: GNU R package "Bindings for the 'Geospatial' Data
Description-md5: dcc7897691b63c85f35105f1e67610c7

Package: r-cran-rgdal
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.4-8-1build2
Priority: optional
Section: universe/gnu-r
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian R Packages Maintainers <r-pkg-team@alioth-lists.debian.net>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 2929
Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.2-2), r-api-3.5, r-cran-sp (>= 1.1-0), libc6 (>= 2.4), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libgdal26 (>= 3.0.0), libproj15 (>= 6.0.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.9)
Filename: pool/universe/r/r-cran-rgdal/r-cran-rgdal_1.4-8-1build2_amd64.deb
Size: 1921320
MD5sum: d39e76515f0a411844c0ba0729f9a8f8
SHA1: a98b87b5805b84e78c97f1499c6db0c8b0182e3a
SHA256: ec3714e52946f283d726a96614af899184d07e43a64519455e0304e0fb874517
Homepage: https://cran.r-project.org/package=rgdal
Description: GNU R bindings for the geospatial data abstraction library
Description-md5: 731ba318ad90af59b91585a829bc8e5e

$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem installing `rgdal` from a different repository inside R.

```
install.packages("rgdal", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/dncgst/111b74066eaea87c92cdc5211949cd1e